# × 274612 Retrieving and displaying Msql database data on a textarea using a Java application

Tags: java, swing

I have created a MySQL database with 4 columns.I want to read the second column of the database and display it on a text area. I have method display() that is called when i click on a button. The code for the method is:

```
public void display(){
    db=new Database();
    try{
        int n=Integer.parseInt(field.getText());

        ResultSet rset=Database.conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from mymusic where trackNumber like'"+n+"'");
        while(rset.next()){
            area.setText(rset.getString("Songlocation"));
        }
        rset.close();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Database error","Warning",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException numfom)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid Entry","Warning",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

A Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.Lang.NullPointerException is thrown when i execute the code and of cos no display. The database connection is perfect since i can update the database successfully. assist me print the data on the text-area.

Comment: Is `Songlocation` a valid column name in `mymusic`?  Does the query directly return results from the database?

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the exception as well, and indicate the actual line where it happens

Comment: 1) `area.setText(rset.getString("Songlocation"));`  Should be `area.append(rset.getString("Songlocation"));` 2) The text area should be a list. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Factor out the DB and instead hard-code the data.

Comment: Further to the comment by @Robin - never ignore exceptions in broken code!  By 'ignore' I mean ignore the stack trace.  For each catch, call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: curious: what's the meaning of the number in the title?

Answer (score 1):

Without the full stack trace it is hard to determine what exactly caused the `NullPointerException`.

Looking at the source code the `Integer.parseInt` will not throw a `NullPointerException` when passing `null`, and the `JTextArea#setText` can handle a `null` value as well.

The remaining candidates: `field` can be `null`, `rset` can be `null` (unlikely as that would trigger NPE's at other locations in the code), `area` can be `null` . Should be pretty straight-forward to determine when you have the stacktrace or use a debugger.

Next to that, some other advise:

- You should move your `rset.close()` statement in a `finally` block to make sure it gets closed, even when an exception occurs
- You should not query the database on the Event Dispatch Thread. Use a worker thread instead. Database access is a slow operation, which will result in a blocked UI until the query is completed. See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information